# Opening a pop up window makes my current window some text area disabled

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a Simple e-archiving system, once I click the NEW button the disabled text areas and buttonsare now being enabled when clicked, but when I try to click another button (near SOLD TO area, it pops up another window) which attaches a specific details of a company, the enabled text areas and other buttons becomes disabled back to its original state, it must be enabled all the time once the NEW button is clicked. What do you think is the problem?

Here's my whole html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>e-Scan Archiving - Accounting</title>
        <link href="main1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.resizeTo(900, 600);
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"><!--
            function codename(e, elm) {
                if(document.formname.New)
                    {
                        document.formname.Add.disabled=false;
                        document.formname.Cancel.disabled=false;
                        document.formname.SapCode.disabled=false;
                        document.formname.LaneCode.disabled=false;
                        document.formname.SoldTo.disabled=false;
                        document.formname.attachmentSoldto.disabled=false;
                        document.formname.SoldAddress.disabled=false;
                        document.formname.ContactPerson.disabled=false;
                        document.formname.DeliveredTo.disabled=false;
                        document.formname.attachmentDeliveredto.disabled=false;
                        document.formname.DeliveredAddress.disabled=false;
                        document.formname.ContactNumber.disabled=false;
                        document.formname.MySelect.disabled=false;
                        document.formname.referenceNo.disabled=false;
                        document.formname.dateReceived.disabled=false;
                        document.formname.receivedBy.disabled=false;
                        document.formname.Remarks.disabled=false;
                    }

                else
                    {
                        document.formname.Add.disabled=true;
                        document.formname.Cancel.disabled=true;
                        document.formname.SapCode.disabled=true;
                        document.formname.LaneCode.disabled=true;
                        document.formname.SoldTo.disabled=true;
                        document.formname.attachmentSoldto.disabled=true;
                        document.formname.SoldAddress.disabled=true;
                        document.formname.ContactPerson.disabled=true;
                        document.formname.DeliveredTo.disabled=true;
                        document.formname.attachmentDeliveredto.disabled=true;
                        document.formname.DeliveredAddress.disabled=true;
                        document.formname.ContactNumber.disabled=true;
                        document.formname.MySelect.disabled=true;
                        document.formname.referenceNo.disabled=true;
                        document.formname.dateReceived.disabled=true;
                        document.formname.receivedBy.disabled=true;
                        document.formname.Remarks.disabled=true;
                    }

                if(elm.type=='button')
                    {
                        var e = e || window.event;
                        if(e)
                         e.preventDefault()
                        elm.type='submit';
                        elm.value="Save";
                        elm.className= 'btn4';
                        elm.name= "Save";
                    }              
            }

            //window pop for QUERY
            function windowpop(width, height) {
                var leftPosition, topPosition;
                //Allow for borders.
                leftPosition = (window.screen.width / 2) - ((width / 2) + 10);
                //Allow for title and status bars.
                topPosition = (window.screen.height / 2) - ((height / 2) + 50);
                //Open the window.
                window.open("query.html", "Window2", "status=no,height=" + height + ",width=" + width + ",resizable=yes,left=" + leftPosition + ",top=" + topPosition + ",screenX=" + leftPosition + ",screenY=" + topPosition + ",toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,directories=no");
            }

            //window pop for SOLD TO ATTACHMENT
            function windowpop1(width, height) {
                var leftPosition, topPosition;
                //Allow for borders.
                leftPosition = (window.screen.width / 2) - ((width / 2) + 10);
                //Allow for title and status bars.
                topPosition = (window.screen.height / 2) - ((height / 2) + 50);
                //Open the window.
                window.open(".html", "Window2", "status=no,height=" + height + ",width=" + width + ",resizable=yes,left=" + leftPosition + ",top=" + topPosition + ",screenX=" + leftPosition + ",screenY=" + topPosition + ",toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,directories=no");
            }

            //window pop for DELIVERED TO ATTACHMENT
            function windowpop2(width, height) {
                var leftPosition, topPosition;
                //Allow for borders.
                leftPosition = (window.screen.width / 2) - ((width / 2) + 10);
                //Allow for title and status bars.
                topPosition = (window.screen.height / 2) - ((height / 2) + 50);
                //Open the window.
                window.open(".html", "Window2", "status=no,height=" + height + ",width=" + width + ",resizable=yes,left=" + leftPosition + ",top=" + topPosition + ",screenX=" + leftPosition + ",screenY=" + topPosition + ",toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,directories=no");
            }

        //-->
        </SCRIPT>
        <div id="container">
            <form method="post" name="formname">
                <div id="header">
                    <div id="img">
                        <img src="dimensiondata.jpg" alt="dimension data" width="250" height="60">
                    </div>
                    <div id="indexno">
                        <center>Index No.</center>  <input type="text" name="indexNo" size="13"> 
                    </div>                  
                        <input type="button" onclick="codename(event, this)" id="myButton1" value="New" class="btn" name="New" style="height: 60px; width: 90px"/>
                        <input type="submit" disabled value="Add" class="btn1" name="Add" style="height: 60px; width: 90px">
                        <button class="btn2" target="_blank" onclick="return windowpop(545, 433)" name="Query" style="height: 60px; width: 90px">Query</button>
                        <input type="submit" disabled value="Cancel" class="btn3" name="Cancel" style="height: 60px; width: 90px">                  
                </div>

                <div id="center">

                        <div id="topleft">                      
                            <b>Category Entry</b><font color="red">*</font>&nbsp    
                                <input type="radio" name="category" value="commercial">Commercial
                                <input type="radio" name="category" value="noncommercial">Non-Commercial<br><br>                        
                        </div>

                        <div id="topright">
                            <div id="topr">
                                Sap Code/SO<br>
                                <input type="text" disabled name="SapCode" size="24">
                            </div>

                            <div id="topl">
                                Lane Box Code<br>
                                <input type="text" disabled name="LaneCode" size="24">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    <div id="left">
                        Sold To<font color="red">*</font><br>
                        <textarea disabled cols="51" rows="2" name="SoldTo"></textarea><button disabled class="btnA" target="_blank" onclick="return windowpop1(545, 433)" name="attachmentSoldto" style="height: 40px; width: 32px">...</button><br>

                        Sold Address<br>
                        <textarea disabled cols="57" rows="2" name="SoldAddress"></textarea><br>

                        Contact Person<br>
                        <input type="text" disabled name="ContactPerson" size="56">                 
                    </div>

                    <div id="right">
                        Delivered To<br>
                        <textarea disabled cols="51" rows="2" name="DeliveredTo"></textarea><button disabled class="btnA" target="_blank" onclick="return windowpop2(545, 433)" name="attachmentDeliveredto" style="height: 40px; width: 32px">...</button><br>

                        Delivered Address<br>
                        <textarea disabled cols="57" rows="2" name="DeliveredAddress"></textarea><br>

                        Contact Number<br>
                        <input type="text" disabled name="ContactNumber" size="56">                 
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="footerleft">
                    <div id="bottomleft">
                        Attachment Value
                    </div>

                    <div id="bottomright">
                        Attachment Type
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="footerright">
                    Attachment Type<font color="red">*</font>

                        <select disabled name="MySelect" id="myselect" size="0">
                        </select>

                    Reference Number<font color="red">*</font> <input type="text" disabled name="referenceNo" size="31">

                    Date Received<font color="red">*</font>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Received By<font color="red">*</font><br>
                    <input type="text" disabled name="dateReceived" size="12">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <input type="text" disabled name="receivedBy" size="34">

                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Remarks</td> 
                            <td><textarea disabled cols="45" rows="2" name="Remarks"></textarea></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

and here's my css:

```
.btn, .btn4{
    margin-left: 395px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.btn1{
    margin-left: 490px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.btn2{
    margin-left: 585px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.btn3{
    margin-left: 680px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

textarea
{
    resize: none;
}

html *
{
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1;
}


#container
{
    margin: auto;
    width: 49em;
    height: 32em;
    background: #E3E3E3;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 1em;
}


#header
{
    margin: auto;
    width: 48em;
    height: 4em;
    background: #DCDCDC;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

#center
{   
    margin: auto;
    width: 48em;
    height: 14em;
    background: #DCDCDC;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    padding: 0.5em;
}


#img
{
    margin-left: 0em;
    width: 250px;
    height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;

}

#indexno
{
    margin-left: 16em;
    margin-top: auto;
    height: 45px;
    width: 116px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0.4em;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

#topleft
{
    clear: left;
    margin-left: 0em;
    float: left;
    height: 2.5em;
    width: 24em;
    background: #DCDCDC;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
}

#topright
{
    float: right;
    height: 3em;
    width: 23.5em;
    background: #DCDCDC;
}

#topl
{
    clear: left;
    height: 3em;
    width: 11em;
    float: left;
    background: #DCDCDC;
}

#topr
{
    height: 3em;
    width: 12em;
    float: right;
    background: #DCDCDC;
}

#left
{
    clear: left;
    width: 23.5em;
    height: 10em;   
    float: left;
    background: #DCDCDC;
}

#right
{
    width: 23.5em;
    height: 10em;
    float: right;
    background: #DCDCDC;
}

#footerleft
{
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    clear: left;
    width: 24em;
    height: 10.5em; 
    float: left;
    background: #DCDCDC;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
}

#footerright
{
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    width: 23.5em;
    height: 10.5em;
    float: right;
    background: #DCDCDC;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#bottomleft
{
    clear: left;
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 11.5em;
    float: left;
    background: #DCDCDC;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
}

#bottomright
{
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 11.5em;
    float: right;
    background: #DCDCDC;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
}

#myselect 
{ 
    width: 365px; 
}

.btnA{
    margin-left: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

*Note: please do NOT try to run the code in jsfiddle, it does not run correctly, try to test it in google chrome, thank you!

Comment: Ohhh, your code could use so much optimization...

Comment: My goal is when I click the button `New` button all the forms are going to be enabled, then there is a pop up window when I click the `...` button, but everytime I click that and the pop up window shows up, all the enabled forms goes back to being disabled. It must not go back to being disabled, what do you think is wrong?